# How to prove that $\sin(\theta)= 2\sin(\theta/2)\cos(\theta/2)$?

Tags: trigonometry

$$\sin (\theta) = 2 \sin \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) \cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$

How? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [$\sin \theta = \sin\!\left(\frac{\theta}{2}+\frac{\theta}{2}\right)
 $](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities)

Comment: Show us your work.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Do you know $\sin(A+B)=?$

Set $A=B=\dfrac{\theta}2$

Answer (score 3):

You know the double angle identity $\sin(2x)=2\sin x\cos x$.

Now substitute $x=\theta/2$.

Answer (score 1):

If you know complex numbers, you can also use:

$e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$ with $e^{i\theta} = (e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}})^2$ (this "trick" yields De Moivre's formula).

Look at the imaginary part of that expression.

Comment: Suifan Pei, very logical solution.